# Unable to give priority to button clicks when sidebar is toggled on smaller screens

Tags: javascript, css

Here's my codepen:
https://codepen.io/rjtbansal/pen/BaLawaO

Basically I have Expand/Collapse button which is toggling to show/hide sidebar. On smaller screens (less than 500px width) it should auto-collapse. I have been able to accomplish this with a media query. However, I would like the button take precedence so even after auto-collapsing when the button is clicked it should then expand/collapse the sidebar.

Here's the HTml:

```
  <body>
    
    <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
      Sidebar
    </div>
    
    <button id="toggle"> Expand/Collapse </button>
   
  </body>
```

css:

```
body {
        background-color: #1d2126;
        color: white;
        height: 100%;
        
      }
          
      .sidebar {
        width: 300px;
        background-color: yellow;
        color: black;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
      }
      
      .sidebar--collapse {
        display: none; 
      }
      
      .sidebar--expand {
       display: block; 
      }
      
      button {
       position: absolute; 
      }
      
      @media screen and (max-width: 500px){   
        .sidebar {
          display: none;
        }
      }
```

js:

```
const toggleButton = document.querySelector("#toggle");
    
    toggleButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      const sidebar = document.querySelector("#sidebar");
      const sidebarClasses = sidebar.classList;
      
      if(sidebarClasses.contains('sidebar--expand')){
           sidebar.classList.remove('sidebar--expand');
           sidebar.classList.add('sidebar--collapse');
      }
      else {
        sidebar.classList.remove('sidebar--collapse');
        sidebar.classList.add('sidebar--expand'); 
      }
                                  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the !imprtant keywork.

```
.sidebar--expand {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: But this no longer auto-collapses. What I want is to auto-collapse as soon as we reduce the screen size. And only then when we click a button it should open again.

Comment: I think this will do the job, because it works on small screens. That's the goal right ? Nobody will shrink his browser to 500px and work with that. The thing you can do is hide the button until its 500px as well if you don't want to have this issue.